# How to read and display in listview SMS messages sort from old to new messages

Tags: android

> I want to display all the messages from devices to listview sorted from old messages to new messages. Currently my code display from new messages up to old messages. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

[image]

```
     ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

 public void displaymessage(){
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items);
    ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = cResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    do{
        str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) ;
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    }while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Change the last argument in the `query()` call from `null` to `"date"`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you!